# Flutter unusual error in errors_patch.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, flutter-state

whenver I run my application, I run into this error in errors_patch.dart

```
  external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
```

here is my entire file if it helps

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class PlayAudioBookScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> initialChapterData;
  final Map<String, dynamic> audioBookData;
  const PlayAudioBookScreen(this.initialChapterData, this.audioBookData, {super.key});

  @override
  State<PlayAudioBookScreen> createState() => PlayAudioBookScreenState();
}

class PlayAudioBookScreenState extends State<PlayAudioBookScreen> {
  AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
  bool playing = true;
  double sliderPos = 0;
  String bookTitle = "";
  String chapterTitle = "";
  String author = "";
  String audioFileLocalPath = "";
  String audioFileFirebasePath = "";
  int audioFileDuration = 0; // is in milliseconds
  Map<String, dynamic> currentChapterData = jsonDecode("{}");
  // in the below, bear in mind im limited by the variables (and equivalently the parameters) of the
  // PlayAudioBookScreen class must be final, so i cant just update the chapterData variable to the
  // next chapters data when reaching the end of the file.
  // a possible way of modifying the current chapter data used by the widget on the fly is by doing what
  // ive done with the commented out chapterData2 variable below here. just make a chapterData2 variable
  // like this, initialize it to widget.chapterData inside initState(), and then update it to the next
  // chapters data when reaching the end of the file.
  // other options would be to pop this screen and push a new one with the next chapters data, or to
  // have some global state management system like provider or bloc that i can consult to ask what
  // chapter where on now.
  // or even just provide the chapter number as a parameter called startChapter or sth, and inside the
  // state class have a "currentChapter" variable that is initialized to startChapter, and then updated
  // accordingly, and just get the chapter data of the currentChapter variable from audioBookData on an
  // adhoc basis.

  @override
  void initState() {
    bookTitle = widget.audioBookData["title"];
    author = widget.audioBookData["author"];
    currentChapterData = widget.initialChapterData;
    chapterTitle = currentChapterData["title"];
    audioFileLocalPath = currentChapterData["localPath"];
    audioFileFirebasePath = currentChapterData["firebasePath"];
    setupPlayer();
    super.initState();
  }

  void setupPlayer() async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File audioFile = File("${appDocDir.path}/$audioFileLocalPath");
    if (!await audioFile.exists()) {
      // should have some error handling here if the download is unsuccessful in case the user is online,
      // maybe in other places of the app too <skull emoji>
      audioFile.create(recursive: true);
      print("come in here3");
      Reference audioFileFirebaseRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(audioFileFirebasePath);
      await audioFileFirebaseRef.writeToFile(audioFile);
    }
    await player.setUrl(audioFile.path);
    player.createPositionStream();

    audioFileDuration = player.duration!.inMilliseconds;
    player.positionStream.listen((position) {
      if (position.inMilliseconds >= audioFileDuration) {
        if (int.parse(currentChapterData["chapterNumber"]) < widget.audioBookData["chapters"].length) {
          print("come in here");
          int nextChapterNumber = int.parse(currentChapterData["chapterNumber"]) + 1;
          print("I see this print statement");
          setupNewChapter(widget.audioBookData["chapters"][nextChapterNumber]);
        } else {
          print("acc here");
          player.pause();
          setState(() {
            sliderPos = audioFileDuration.toDouble();
            playing = false;
          });
        }
      } else {
        setState(() {
          sliderPos = position.inMilliseconds.toDouble();
        });
      }
    });

    player.play();
    setState(() {
      playing = true;
    });
  }

  void setupNewChapter(Map<String, dynamic> chapterData) {
    print("but dont see this print statement");
    currentChapterData = chapterData;
    print("come in here3");
    chapterTitle = currentChapterData["title"];
    print("come in her4S");
    audioFileLocalPath = currentChapterData["localPath"];
    print("come in here2");
    audioFileFirebasePath = currentChapterData["firebasePath"];
    print("come in here2");
    setupPlayer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 80),
        Text(bookTitle, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        Text(chapterTitle, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        Text("by $author"),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        playing
            ? IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.pause),
                onPressed: () async {
                  player.pause();
                  setState(() {
                    playing = false;
                  });
                },
              )
            : IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                onPressed: () async {
                  player.play();
                  setState(() {
                    playing = true;
                  });
                },
              ),
        Slider(
            min: 0,
            max: audioFileDuration.toDouble(),
            value: sliderPos,
            onChanged: (value) async {
              await player.seek(Duration(milliseconds: value.toInt()));
            }),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

but there doesn't seem to be any explanation online that I can find as to what this error means. I have put print statements and I see up to the print statement that says "I see this print statement" but then I dont see the one that says "but I dont see this one"

Comment: You need to walk the code using the ide debugger it is crashing at some point and you need to find where. You could put also put more print statements.

Comment: I think you should try `setupPlayer` with FutureBuilder

Comment: thanks @GrahamD, I will try to, and I found the point it breaks using print statements but I'll try the debugger

Comment: If you are using VSCode, which is the one I know best, maybe try selecting 'all errors' in the run section. Also check what the stack shows you at the crash.

Comment: If you need more help, post the full error message and stack trace. The code line throwing the error does not provide any information.